# focusOutFront() not working on VerticalGridSupportFragment but working on RowSupportFragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-tv, leanback

I am working on Android TV using Leanback. Here, I have a list of channel data and their EPG. I have populated the channels list on the VerticalGridSupportFragment. And I also have a date filter button to filter the EPG list as per date. Here, is the design of the channel list and EPG with the filter button.

[image]

Now, the problem is I can navigate from the filter button to the channel list. But I cannot navigate from the channel list to the filter button. That means I have to focus out from VerticalGridSupportFragment to focus on other views. I have also tried to add focusOutFront = "true" from the style as well as the custom VerticalGridPresenter but with no luck. Only focus start and end is working, but focus front is not working. This is working on RowSupportFragment but not on VerticalGridSupportFragment.

From Style:

```
<style name="AppThemeLeanbackVerticalGridView" parent="AppThemeLeanback">
    <item name="headersVerticalGridStyle">@style/AppThemeLeanbackHeadersVerticalGridView</item>
    <item name="itemsVerticalGridStyle">@style/AppThemeLeanbackGridItemsVerticalGridView</item>
    <item name="rowsVerticalGridStyle">@style/AppThemeLeanbackHorizontalGridView</item>
</style>

<style name="AppThemeLeanbackHeadersVerticalGridView" parent="Widget.Leanback.Headers.VerticalGridView">
    <item name="focusOutFront">true</item>
    <item name="focusOutEnd">true</item>
    <item name="focusOutSideStart">true</item>
    <item name="focusOutSideEnd">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppThemeLeanbackGridItemsVerticalGridView" parent="Widget.Leanback.GridItems.VerticalGridView">
    <item name="focusOutFront">true</item>
    <item name="focusOutEnd">true</item>
    <item name="focusOutSideStart">true</item>
    <item name="focusOutSideEnd">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppThemeLeanbackHorizontalGridView" parent="Widget.Leanback.Rows.VerticalGridView">
    <item name="focusOutFront">true</item>
    <item name="focusOutEnd">true</item>
    <item name="focusOutSideStart">true</item>
    <item name="focusOutSideEnd">true</item>
</style>
```

From Custom VerticalGridPresenter:

```
class CustomVerticalGridPresenterFocusOut internal constructor(
context: Context,
private val padding: Int,
focusZoomFactor: Int,
useFocusDimmer: Boolean) :
VerticalGridPresenter(focusZoomFactor, useFocusDimmer) {

private lateinit var gridView: VerticalGridView

override fun initializeGridViewHolder(vh: ViewHolder) {
    super.initializeGridViewHolder(vh)
    gridView = vh.gridView
    val top = padding //this is the new value for top padding
    val bottom = gridView.paddingBottom
    val right = gridView.paddingRight
    val left = gridView.paddingLeft
    gridView.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom)

    gridView.setFocusOutSideAllowed(throughStart = true, throughEnd = true)
    gridView.setFocusOutAllowed(throughFront = true, throughEnd = true)
}}
```

Please help me to focus out of the VerticalGridSupportFragment.

Answer (score 1):

Changing `OnFocusSearchListener` for `BrowseFrameLayout` inside `VerticalGridSupportFragment` may solve your problem. You need to give the focus to the list on the left when the `BrowseFrameLayout` is searching for focus. The following code snippet may help:

```java
BrowseFrameLayout browseFrameLayout = (BrowseFrameLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.grid_frame);
browseFrameLayout.setOnFocusSearchListener((focused, direction) -> {
    if (direction == View.FOCUS_LEFT) {
        return viewToFocus; // the list view you want to focus
    }else {
        return null;
    }
});
```